# Deleted a certificate and inserted new certificate in keystore and getting error SSL version mistmatch

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat, keystore

I had integrated a certificate in keystore but had to remove it as domain name was wrong and after that I deleted the certificate using following command:

```
keytool -delete -alias <alias> -keystore <path of keystore>
```

Before this web site was opening with giving error of not correct ssl but now after integerating the correct certificate its giving error as follow:

This site can’t provide a secure connection  uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

Mine is windows server with Tomcat 8

Comment: Who issued newly integrated certificate?

Comment: @AbhiN Digicert issued the certificate

Answer (score 0):

If there is no certificate configured for the server then no cipher can be used which requires a certificate for authentication - which includes every cipher usually configured in server and client. This results in the error message you see. To fix it make sure that you have a valid certificate configured.

Comment: Its seems to be correct certificate..How could I validate certificate... Even if I delete the current certificate and configured the previous one its still giving same error...